# Why I can't insert Html to a DOM element after using .empty()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

While testing Bootstrap tables in JSFiddles, I wanted to make it so that when I click a button inside the table the button would disappear and be replaced by normal text. Here is the relevant part of the markup:

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>my@gmail.com</td>
            <td><button class="disabled" data-bind="click: dosomething.bind($data, 'was', 'sup')" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Crear Cuenta</button></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

So using KnockoutJS to bind an event to when the button is clicked, I did the following:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.dosomething = function (data, event, param1, param2) {
            var $stuff = $(param2.target).prop("disabled",true);
        var $stuff2 = $(param2.target).hasClass("disabled");
        var $stuff3 = $(param2.target).parent();
        $(param2.target).parent().empty();
        $(param2.target).parent().html("hello");
    }

    self.donext = function(){
            var $stuff = $(".disabled").prop("disabled",false);
    }
}

var app = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(app);
```

However, `hello` wouldn't render at all. But when I removed the `$(param2.target).parent().empty();` line, the button would be substituted by `hello` as I originally wanted. If `.empty()` only removes the child contents, why can't I add html content afterwards?

Comment: Is this inside a `foreach` binding? There are easier ways to disable or remove items from the UI in KO. Using jquery like this to remove stuff will lead to undesired behavior.

Comment: @adiga In practice yes. Even though the problem has already been solved, I'm interested in the better ways to remove items from the UI you mentioned. Could you please hint me at what are or where can I learn more about these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
    $(param2.target).parent().empty();
```

empties all the content out of the parent element. If you empty out all the content from the parent element of some other (child) element, what do you suppose happens to the child? Right: it's gone. Thus the subsequent attempt to set the `.html()` content won't work because the parent is no longer the parent.

You can use chaining from the parent element:

```
    $(param2.target).parent().empty().html("hello");
```

That works because the call to `.empty()` returns the jQuery object that wraps the parent. What *doesn't* work in your code is starting over from the (no longer) child element.

Comment: Oh right, I missed such an obvious flaw. Thanks for answering :).